# How do I get the current left and indentations in this code, display them and after that implement the custom ones the user entered in the text edit

Tags: c++, qt

So I have to basically get the current left and right indentations, display them on the text widget and then get the user input for the custom indentations and basically implement them. When I run this program it displays the incorrect indentation values. the minimum and max values of indentations are 0 and 14 respectively. Also when I enter custom values in the dialog box it just increments the values by one sometimes and other times it does nothing. Can someone help me find my mistake?

```
/*!
 * \fn MainWindow::on_actionIncrease_Indent_triggered
 * \brief Adding Indentation upto 14.65 {i.e. touched right margin} {in cm}
*/
void MainWindow::on_actionIncrease_Indent_triggered(int left, int right)
{
    if(!curr_browser || curr_browser->isReadOnly())
        return;
    QMargins margin = curr_browser->contentsMargins();
    QTextCursor cursor = curr_browser->textCursor();

    QTextBlock block = cursor.block();
    QTextBlockFormat blockFormat = block.blockFormat();

    int presentIndent = blockFormat.indent();


    int indent = 1+presentIndent;

    if(left != 0) indent = left;
    if(indent > 14) return;

    if(right == 0)blockFormat.setRightMargin(margin.right());
    else blockFormat.setRightMargin(right);
    blockFormat.setIndent(indent);

    //    qDebug()<<"Increase Indent ->"<<blockFormat.indent();

    cursor.mergeBlockFormat(blockFormat);

}
```

```
/*!
 * \fn MainWindow::on_actionDecrease_Indent_triggered
 * \brief Removing Indentation upto 0 {i.e. touches Left margin} {in cm}
*/
void MainWindow::on_actionDecrease_Indent_triggered()
{
    if(!curr_browser || curr_browser->isReadOnly())
        return;
    QMargins margin = curr_browser->contentsMargins();
    QTextCursor cursor = curr_browser->textCursor();

    QTextBlock block = cursor.block();
    QTextBlockFormat blockFormat = block.blockFormat();

    int presentIndent = blockFormat.indent();

    int indent = presentIndent-1;

    if(indent < 0) return;

    blockFormat.setLeftMargin(margin.left());
    blockFormat.setIndent(presentIndent - 1);

    //    qDebug()<<"Decrease Indent ->"<<blockFormat.indent();

    cursor.mergeBlockFormat(blockFormat);
}
```

```
void MainWindow::on_actionIndentation_Options_triggered()
{
    if(!curr_browser || curr_browser->isReadOnly())
        return;
    QMargins margin = curr_browser->contentsMargins();
    QTextCursor cursor = curr_browser->textCursor();
    QTextBlock block = cursor.block();
    QTextBlockFormat blockFormat = block.blockFormat();
    int left = blockFormat.indent(), right = margin.right() - blockFormat.rightMargin();
    indentOptions *i = new indentOptions(this, &left, &right);
    i->show();
    connect(i, &indentOptions::dialogAccepted, this, [=](){
        if(left + right <= 14){
            on_actionIncrease_Indent_triggered(left, right);
        }
        i->deleteLater();
    });
}
```

```
indentOptions::indentOptions(QWidget *parent, int* left, int* right) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::indentOptions)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->left = left;
    this->right = right;
    setWindowTitle("Set Indentation");
    ui->textEdit_left->setText(QString::number(*left));
    ui->textEdit_right->setText(QString::number(*right));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you initialized `ui->textEdit_left`s text with value obtained through the pointer `left`, this doesn't create any binding between value and text, when user edits text, value of `left` does not change automagicaly.

Even if they were bounded, it wont work, since lambda function captured `left` by value not by reference, so `left` is always equals to `blockFormat.indent()` for lambda function (lambda holds copy of value not reference to it).

Even if they were bounded and `left` was captured by reference, it wont work, since local variable `left` is destroyed by the time user accepts dialog, since dialog is not modal, pointers and references to `left` will be invalid by then, accessing values over invalid pointers leads to undefined behaviour (SEGFAULT or random value).

To get what user inputs you need to access edit's text and convert it back to int. To do that you need to implement getter functions as I suggested before.

```cpp
class indentOptions {
...
public:
    int left() const;
    int right() const;
}

int indentOptions::left() const {
    return ui->textEdit_left->text().toInt();
}

int indentOptions::right() const {
    return ui->textEdit_right->text().toInt();
}

connect(i, &indentOptions::dialogAccepted, this, [=](){
    int left = i->left();
    int right = i->right();
    if(left + right <= 14){
        on_actionIncrease_Indent_triggered(left, right);
    }
    i->deleteLater();
});
```

You can cover cases when used inputs invalid (nonnumber) text by holding copies of initial values (not pointers) inside `indentOptions` and returning them instead.

```cpp
class indentOptions {
...
    indentOptions(QWidget *parent, int left, int right);
protected:
    int m_left; 
    int m_right;
}

indentOptions::indentOptions(QWidget *parent, int left, int right) : QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::indentOptions), m_left(left), m_right(right) {
...
}

int indentOptions::left() const {
    bool ok;
    int value = ui->textEdit_left->text().toInt(&ok);
    if (ok) {
        return value;
    }
    return m_left;
}
```